# Numbered fieldsets appearing in checkboxes cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2

I am using cakephp 2.2.0, in that I am displaying checkboxes for multiple selection, everything is working fine except, It shows numbers in fieldsets with every checkbox. I want to remove that, What should I do? Below is my code for checkbox in ctp file.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Student.sub_id', array(    
                                                        'type' => 'select',
                                                        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                                        'options' => $sub
                                                    ));
```

In **Student.sub_id, sub_id (varchar)** is my field of students table.

And in this code displays checkboxes like: [image: checkboxes]

and in `'options' => $sub`
when I print array **$sub** (print_r), It displays something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [3] => Maths
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [4] => Science
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [5] => PHP
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [6] => Java
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [7] => C++
        )

)
```

So, What should I do to remove numbers?

Comment: You should use a non-multidimensional array. Either retrieve your data differently (CakePHP has find('list')) or manipulate the array.
Key=>value,
Key=>value

Comment: @wiseguysonly, how to manipulate the array? I am not getting the idea of manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using ->find('list') for students, remove .subid

```
echo $this->Form->input('Student', array(    
                                        'type' => 'select',
                                        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                         'options' => $sub
                                        ));
```

Comment: I am not using find('list'), but even if I use it, I want to display the subject names after each checkbox and I want to get the id of the subject (as checkbox is checked).